# Grothendieck decomposition of locally free sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{P}^1 \rightarrow X$ be a morphism with $X$ a smooth projective algebraic variety of dimension $n$, then by Grothendieck $\mathcal{N}_{f}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^{n-1}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a_i)$, where $\mathcal{N}_{f}$ is the normal sheaf associated to $f$.

Is there some relation between those $a_{is}$ and the properties  of the  morphism $f$? and what is the geometric interpretation?.

..for example if $X$ has dimension $2$ then $\mathcal{N}_{f}=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a_1)$ thus $a_{1}=c_{1}(\mathcal{N}_{f})$ (the first Chern class of the normal sheaf)  and it is the autointersection of $f(\mathbb{P}^1)\subset X$ , but in higher cases $c_{1}(\mathcal{N}_{f})=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i$ and then I don't know what is the relation between them... I wanna find a geometric interpretation of those $a_is$ in $f$.
Anyone could help me with this ?

Comment: There is a huge literature about this. You might start with Kollár's *Rational curves on algebraic varieties*.

Comment: Yes i am reading this book and Debarre  , but i didnt find some about this coefficients

Comment: Come on! The coefficients tell you how your map deforms, a fundamental tool in algebraic geometry. Read better.

Comment: for example i kow that $H^{0}(\mathcal{N}_f)$ and $H^{1}(\mathcal{N}_f)$ tell me first order deformations and obstruction , if $a_i >-1$ for all $i$  then $f(\mathbb{P}^1)$ does not has obstruction, but which is the relation between $a_i$ and the way of deformate $f$

Comment: @abx, I don't think the "Come on!" and "Read better" are appropriate or needed in your comment.

Comment: Looking at the proof of the result should answer this. On th eother hand, I hope we get an enlightening answer from a member of the community :)

Comment: @user347489  thank u ..do u have any reference for this ?, because i know that all locally free sheaf over $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a sum of line bundles and all line bundles over  $\mathbb{P}^1$ looks like $\mathcal{O}(d)$ for d an integer...i thought that in  the prooff dont construct this line bundles only use the fact that how they looks like..